# How to raise an Error for the completionHandler?

Tags: swift, unit-testing, error-handling

I'm in process of unittesting a case where the completionHandler is throwing an error. But I'm not sure how to raise that error.

```
class MockErrorSession: URLSessionProtocol {
    var nextDataTask = MockURLSessionDataTask()
    var nextData: Data?
    var nextError: Error?

    func dataTask(with request: NSURLRequest, completionHandler: @escaping DataTaskResult) -> URLSessionDataTaskProtocol {

        nextError = ?

        completionHandler(nextData, successHttpURLResponse(request: request), nextError)
        return nextDataTask as URLSessionDataTaskProtocol
    }
}
```

I need somehow to populate `nextError`

I tried to do this,

```
enum MyError : Error {
   case RuntimeError(String)
}

func throwError(_ message: String) throws {
   throw MyError.RuntimeError(message)
}

nextError = try throwError("test") as! Error
```

Any advice please?

Comment: But your `dataTask(with:completionHandler:)` is not marked with `throws` or `rethrows`. Infact you would require `rethrows` if a closure throws. Can you share non-unit test code where the throwing actually works?

Comment: ok, how about this... is `dataTask(with:completionHandler:)` supposed to throw or will the error be thrown inside the `completionHandler`?

Comment: What does your `DataTaskResult` typealias declaration look like? Is it **1.** `typealias DataTaskResult = (Data?, URLResponse, Error?) -> Void` or **2.** `typealias DataTaskResult = (Data?,URLResponse,Error?) throws -> Void`

Comment: I'll answer assuming there's no `throw`ing business going on. If otherwise then kindly update your question with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `dataTask(with:completionHandler:)` does not seem to be marked with `throws`/`rethrows` in which case it seems the error is simply being passed to the completion block.

Since neither the function nor the closure "`throws`", you  can't `throw` the error & as a result neither will you be able to `do`-`try`-`catch` it later anyways.

So as per my assumptions, just the following should suffice:

```
nextError = MyError.RuntimeError("test")
```

---

i.e.

```
enum MyError : Error {
   case RuntimeError(String)
}

func dataTask(with request: NSURLRequest, 
              completionHandler: @escaping DataTaskResult) -> URLSessionDataTaskProtocol {

    nextError = MyError.RuntimeError("test")

    completionHandler(nextData, 
                      successHttpURLResponse(request: request),
                      nextError)

    return nextDataTask as URLSessionDataTaskProtocol
}
```